# grails form redirect gives 404, but url mapping works

Tags: forms, grails, redirect, groovy, gsp

I feel like I've entered the Twilight Zone.  I have a Grails form that redirects to a URL, but gives a 404.  If I go directly to that exact URL, everything works fine (that is, the URL mappings are correct).

This is an example generated form tag:

```
<form action="/alm/contactRefresh/itemRefreshProcess/7070" method="post">
```

On submit, it redirects to:

```
http://localhost:8080/alm/contactRefresh/itemRefreshProcess/7070
```

But gives this error:

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /alm/contactRefresh/itemRefreshProcess/7070. Reason:
NOT_FOUND
Powered by Jetty://
```

But then if I just go directly to that same URL (by focusing the browser Location bar and pressing enter), the page renders just fine, though the form params are lost because it's just a GET now.  I've also tried changing the form method to GET, and that doesn't work either (throws a 404).

I've done similar forms a zillion times before with no problems.  I'm sure this is some stupid user error, but I seriously can't figure out what's wrong.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: PS: I've also tried renaming the controller action method and gsp file to something completely different -- doesn't help.

Comment: Also, I can use a REST Client to POST params directly to the URL and everything works perfectly (I get a 200 OK and the expected HTML response).  Grails just cannot redirect to this damned URL for some reason.  I feel like I have gone batshit insane.

Comment: I also just moved the action method and GSP view file to a different controller altogether, updated the <g:form> to point to the new controller.  Same result.

Comment: Also tried three different web browsers.  :)

Comment: I also tried running grails war and deploying in Tomcat instead of Jetty.  Same result.

Comment: I also tried using plain html for the <form> markup instead of <g:form>.  Same result.

Comment: Something must be different. Have you already compared the plain http requests which are send to the server?

Comment: I have the answer now, but the site won't let me answer my own question for another two hours because I'm a new user.  The cause was a checkbox in the form which had a name starting with the word "action" (concatenated with an id).  I'll post a full explanation when the site lets me.

Comment: PS: thanks for your response, Ralf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I finally started ripping parts out of the form and found out that for some reason you can’t name a Grails checkbox starting with the word "action".  It must be something related to the default params["action"] entry.  Though my checkbox names were a concatenation of "action_" + an id.

Anyway, there was some kind pre-processing of the checkbox form params that was blowing up before making it to the controller, and somehow that translated to a 404 instead of an actual Exception.

Originally I had this:

```
<g:checkBox name="action_${serviceRefreshAction.id}" value="${true}" />
```

Which renders this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_action_7196" /><input type="checkbox" name="action_7196" checked="checked" id="action_7196"  />
```

I changed "action" to "myAction", like this:

```
<g:checkBox name="myAction_${serviceRefreshAction.id}" value="${true}" />
```

Which renders this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_myAction_7206" /><input type="checkbox" name="myAction_7206" checked="checked" id="myAction_7206"  />
```

And now everything works fine.

Five hours of my life down the drain.

But I guess I have to forgive Grails, for the all time it saves me on a daily basis normally.  :o)

Comment: I started a thread on the grails-user mailing list, but didn't get much of a response.  I'll try to dig into the source code eventually and come up with a reason this happens.  http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/grails-checkbox-names-cannot-start-with-quot-action-quot-td4495593.html